# librdkafka oauthbearer implementation

Tags: c++, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I am trying to implement SASL/oauthbearer in my cpp kafka producer application using librdkafka v2.2.0,
From the available documentation I've framed the implementation, but oauth_token_refresh_call_back is not working, token not getting refreshed(callback not invoked). I will attach the code snippet , please verify and report the problem/mistakes if any
Is kerberos setup needed ?

```
static void dr_msg_cb(rd_kafka_t *rk, const rd_kafka_message_t *rkmessage, void *opaque) {
    if (rkmessage->err) {
        LOG_FATAL << "Message delivery failed: " << rd_kafka_err2str(rkmessage->err);
    } else {
        LOG_DEBUG << "Message delivered ( " << rkmessage->len << " bytes, partition %" << rkmessage->partition << ")";
    }
}

static void oauthbearer_token_refresh_cb(rd_kafka_t* rk, const char* oauthbearer_config, void* opaque) {

    std::ostringstream ss;
    ptree tokenData = GenUtil::GetoAuthAccessToken(clientId, clientSecret, refToken, url);
    std::string accToken = tokenData.get<std::string>("access_token");
    unsigned long long tokenExpTime = TimeUtil::TimeNow() + tokenData.get<unsigned long long>("expires_in") * 1000;
    boost::property_tree::ptree data;
    data.put("accessTtoken", accToken);
    data.put("expiresIn", tokenExpTime);
    write_json(ss, data, false);
    std::string contentStr = ss.str();
    if ( !accToken.empty()) {
        std::string encodedToken =  base64Encode(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*> (contentStr.c_str()), contentStr.size());
        rd_kafka_oauthbearer_set_token(rk, encodedToken.c_str(), tokenExpTime, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
    } else {
        std::string errStr = "Error in getting access token";
        rd_kafka_oauthbearer_set_token_failure(rk, errStr.c_str());
    }
}


int Init() {

    conf = rd_kafka_conf_new();


    if (rd_kafka_conf_set(conf, "bootstrap.servers", brokers,
            errstr, sizeof (errstr)) != RD_KAFKA_CONF_OK
        || rd_kafka_conf_set(conf, "security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
            errstr, sizeof (errstr)) != RD_KAFKA_CONF_OK 
        || rd_kafka_conf_set(conf, "sasl.mechanism", "OAUTHBEARER",
            errstr, sizeof (errstr)) != RD_KAFKA_CONF_OK ) {
        LOG_FATAL << "Error in rd_kafka_conf_set(): " << errstr;
        return 1;
    }
    
    // custom call back function 
    rd_kafka_conf_set_dr_msg_cb(conf, dr_msg_cb); 

    rk = rd_kafka_new(RD_KAFKA_PRODUCER, conf, errstr, sizeof (errstr));
    if (!rk) {
        LOG_ERROR << "Failed to create new producer: %s\n" << errstr;
        return 1;
    }
    
    //enable sasl background calls
    rd_kafka_sasl_background_callbacks_enable(rk);

    //topic creation
    rkt = rd_kafka_topic_new(rk, topic, NULL);
    if (!rkt) {
        LOG_ERROR << "Failed to create topic object: %s\n" << rd_kafka_err2str(rd_kafka_last_error());      
        rd_kafka_destroy(rk);
        return 1;
    }
    
    // token refresh callback
    rd_kafka_conf_set_oauthbearer_token_refresh_cb(conf, oauthbearer_token_refresh_cb);
    // enable ssl queue 
    rd_kafka_conf_enable_sasl_queue(conf, 1);
    return 0;
}

int Send(std::string data) {
    new char [data.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(b, data.c_str());

RETRY:
    if (rd_kafka_produce(
            rkt,
            RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA,
            RD_KAFKA_MSG_F_COPY,
            b,
            data.length(),
            NULL, 0,
            NULL) != 0) {
        LOG_FATAL << "%% Failed to produce to topic" << rd_kafka_topic_name(rkt) << ": " << rd_kafka_err2str(rd_kafka_last_error());


        if (rd_kafka_last_error() == RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__QUEUE_FULL) {
            rd_kafka_poll(rk, 1000/*block for max 1000ms*/);
            goto RETRY;
        }
    } else {
        LOG_FATAL << "%% Enqueued message (" << data.length() << " bytes) for topic " << rd_kafka_topic_name(rkt);
    }
    delete b;

    rd_kafka_poll(rk, 0/*non-blocking*/);
    int err = rd_kafka_last_error();
    LOG_FATAL << err;
    return err;
}
```